# SMTP on AWS private subnet EC2, Network unreachable [errorno 101]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, smtplib, private-subnet

Trying to send emails using SMTPlib in python script on **private subnet** EC2 machine using following code. EC2 machine has communication with internal SMTP server through `PORT 25` , verified using `telnet` command.
This code works fine from public subnet EC2 but throws error mentioned at the bottom on private subnet.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart  #python 2


msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'myid@domain.com'
msg['To'] = 'youid@domain.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email in python'
message = 'here is the email'


mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',25)

mailserver.ehlo()

mailserver.starttls()

mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('myid@domain.com', 'password')

mailserver.sendmail('myid@domain.com','youid@domain.com',msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()
```

Getting this error `socket.error: errorno[101] - Network is unreachable`

Answer (score 0):

- do you have a NAT gateway in the private subnet where your smtp is located?
- do you have active access control layer on that private subnet where your server is located? Is it blocking anything?
- also check ACL rules in public subnet
- security group attached to the server, is it open?

Answer (score 0):

Email server configuration was wrong and the email server did not require login.

```
mailserver = smtplib.SMTP(internal office server,25)


#mailserver.login('myid@domain.com', 'password') -- Not required for the server
```

Thank you.